# MS Access 2010 - New subform built works the first time it opens, but is not refreshing, when the parent form's record is refreshed with a 2nd record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm working in MS Access 2010, on an undocumented legacy application.

I have an existing Form A, with 4 different pages (tabs) within it.

`A1   A2   A3   A4`

Form A4 also has 4 pre-existing sub-forms within it.

`B1  B2  B3   B4`

I have now created a new sub-form B5, built upon a query to find and display a related record, to the record displayed in A2.

So now, my subforms are:

`B5   B1    B2     B3      B4`

When I first search for a first parent record, and load the A1-A4 forms with the results, my associated data displayed in my new form B5 is correct.

The mapped Source Object setting is to my new query, and is executing.

Working as intended.

However, the 2nd time I search for a new, second parent record, and the A1-A4 forms reload with the 2nd results, but when I click on my new form B5, it is still showing the same record, from the first search/results.   It is not refreshing and finding the new associated record, but seems to be stuck on the first associated record.  Instead of showing the associated record, for the 2nd set of results, as it should.

When I open the query that my new sub-form is built upon, and Run it, it IS showing the new 2nd result, instead of the 1st result.  So it's working correctly, but the form built on it is "stuck" on the first record.

Is there a certain other form property that needs to be used, in order to make this sub-form refresh with the new data?  And if so, using what code, expression or value?

And Enabled = Yes, and Locked = No.

Does it have anything to do with being assigned the position of Page Index = 0 (first in list of subforms)?

TIA

I'e noticed that the other existing sub forms (B1-B4) are also not refreshing with "new" second set of results either, so don't provide an example either, to refer to.  And my users are not concerned about what those other sub-forms are doing, at least not yet.

Right now the new sub-form's OnClick property is set to this Event (an empty sub in the VBA)

```
Private Sub B5()

End Sub
```

Instead of showing the associated record, for the 2nd set of results, as the new subform B5 should.

Comment: Have you set Master/Child Links properties of subform container control?

Comment: I tried setting this, matching ID values in the pull downs.  But not sure I was doing it right, as it didn't resolve.  And this setting in MS Access was not very richly described in the information I found describing it.  Can you offer a richer description of how this is supposed to work?    And, does it control how data refreshed on master form triggers how data is refreshed on sub-form?  Or do you also have to use another setting as well, in conjunction with that?

Comment: If you linked two primary key ID fields, that would not be correct. Main form primary key must link to subform foreign key field.

Comment: Thanks, it was only one ID linked to another ID.   For reasons undocumented,  these IDs as keys to each other were removed in the past.  But would it still work if the ID values match the ID values?   Or is there an actual dependency between form and sub-form, to have these be PK and FK with relationship?      We have limitations for resources being able to fix any integrity issues that might occur, if we try to re-establish the PK-FK relationship.

Comment: Let me restate - If you link two autonumber fields (autonumber usually created with name ID), that would never be correct. If you link two fields that are both defined as primary key (no duplicates allowed) then you have a 1-to-1 relationship. Still, one field must be considered dependent on the other. Master/Child Links synchronize related records. This is basic Access functionality.

Comment: These are not autonumber fields that are linked.  These are not two primary keys that are linked.                                                                                    
     These are two fields in two different tables, that have same values assigned by users, in two different forms.  But they are not set up as foreign keys.  That was the scope of my follow up question.     Does the Master/Child linking between form/sub-form have any dependency upon the two fields being related as foreign keys?

Comment: Even if neither field is defined as PK, synchronization should still be possible. You say B1-B4 are subforms within A4. But you say B5 is dependent on A2. Exactly where is B5 located in relation to A2? Are you using Tab control or a Navigation form?

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  We do have the Master - Child fields linked, via a non-keyed set of fields, that have matching values.    Never could get B5 to work as the new sub-form of another pre-existing sub-form.  So redid it, and moved it up a level, and now it's just another new subform at the first level, depending on information in A2.  And that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someday this will be useful?

Access Form Refresh Help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.refresh

Access Form Requery Help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.requery

Referring to form/subform from another form/subform, especially updating recordsources http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: Thanks the for the links.  The first two, about just Forms, were what I found as well.  But it's hard to find the same type of overview/description of sub-forms.  Especially when you have subforms of subforms.    The 3rd link looks interesting, and I'll take a look at the matrix, to see if I can fully understand all its' trying to describe in one place.  A few paragraphs of what is being described (like found in those Forms articles) would be useful to go with it, regarding the sub-forms behaviors.  Thanks again